Как обойти ошибку Certificate public key has explicit ECC parameters?
При попытке проверить сертификат подписи биометрического паспорта (Стандарт ICAO 9303 (MRTD)) OpenSSL выводит следующую ошибку:
error 94 at 0 depth lookup: Certificate public key has explicit ECC parameters

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно обойти данную ошибку?

